# sql for counting null in between and inserting number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with column c1.I need c2 like this:

```
    C1        C2
(somevalue)   3
(somevalue)   3
   NULL       3 
(somevalue)   2
   NULL       2
(somevalue)   3
   NULL       3
   NULL       3
(somevalue)   2
   NULL       2
(somevalue)   1
```

Logic:count rows that are not null until a null is found followed by a not null value, including the nulls, but without the following value. Start counting again when null is crossed until next null is found.

Comment: How is the order of rows determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the answer to the original question where the OP wanted to count NULL values.

```
    C1        C2
   NULL       3
   NULL       3 
(somevalue)   3
   NULL       4
   NULL       4
   NULL       4
(somevalue)   4
   NULL       2
(somevalue)   2
```

Assuming the columns are to be ordered by an id column, this might be what you want:

```
select id, c1, x, y,
    count(1) over (partition by y) z
from(
    select id, c1, x,
        LAG(x,1,x) over (order by id) y
    from (
        select 
            id, 
            c1, 
            count(c1) over (order by id) x 
        from test
    )
)
order by id;
```

Of course you can remove the superfluous columns from the outermost select statement.

[There is a Sql Fiddle for it.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6091/14)

An answer for the current version can be obtained by replacing C1 in the answer with decode(c1,null, 'x', null) and possibly some minor adjustments for border cases.

Comment: it assumes NULL as zero and counts the value alone.moreover i dont think this can be done in a single query.think a plsql will do.

Comment: yeah, I just now understood the question. it's the first step. Just wait a second.

Comment: @theDbGuy Oracle SQL ist turing complete (if you ignore space limitations)http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2009/06/18/building-a-turing-engine-in-oracle-sql-using-the-model-clause/

Comment: the algo fails for the new c1 edited.do u find anything

Comment: the example does not match the description. And I don't understand the example now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach with a cursor (assuming table is ordered by an id column):

```
    declare @id int, @C1 varchar(15), @C2 int, @counter int
    select @counter = 0
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR             
            SELECT id, C1, C2 FROM tableName order by id
    OPEN cursor1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @id, @C1, @C2;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        if (@C1 is NULL)
            select @counter = @counter + 1
        else
        begin
            select @counter = @counter + 1
            update tableName set C2 = @counter where id = @id 
            select @id, @C1, @C2, @counter
            select @counter = 0 
        end

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @id, @C1, @C2;   
    END
    CLOSE cursor1;
    DEALLOCATE cursor1;
```

Happy coding!